# Nokogiri - How to select the attribute "value" from nokogiri page search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have used Nokogiri to search by css class and received this output. I would like to select:  value="E-Mail an application-.com" from this hash but I cant figure out how. This is the hash:

```
{"href"=>#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe935c500b8 name="href"   
value="http://.com">, "chars"=>#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe935c500a4    
name="chars" value="q|c|.|i|@|l|t|e|j|o|a|m|u|n|p">, "chars_index"=># 
<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe935c50090 name="chars_index" 
value="10|14|14|5|3|1|10|6|3|9|13|4|8|12|13|3|0|7|2|1|9|11">, "title"=>#     
<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe935c5007c name="title" value="E-Mail an 
application-.com">}
```

I have tried to select the values using

```
.select{|a| a['value']}
```

but this does not work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is nicely covered in the Nokogiri documentation and questions on SO. When asking, we need the minimal HTML, not the output of inspecting a variable. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1):

http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/

This is covered nicely in the above link.

It might be easier to select the name:
i.e after using the appropriate css selectors, your last statement would look like :

```
 page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL))

 page.css(//some selectors...[title="name"])
```

Comment: Interesting reference!

Comment: This method did not work for me although i found the following did  page.css(".selector")[0]['title']

Comment: You don't want to use `css` with what appears to be an attempt to use XPath. Nokogiri will (correctly) assume you're passing in a CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is using [`#attribute`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Reader#attribute-instance_method) on the node.

```
page.css(a_selector).map{ |node| node.attribute('value') }
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat a node like it's a hash if you want to access an attribute:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<a href="foo">bar</a>')
doc.at('a')['href'] # => "foo"
```

You'll see that notation used most commonly.

Alternately you can use these:

```
doc.at('a').get_attribute('href') # => "foo"
doc.at('a').attr('href')          # => "foo"
```

These are documented in [Nokogiri's XML::Node documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node).